# Can Isabelle lemma be used for stating fact about definition?

Tags: isabelle, isar

I have Isabelle definition:

```
definition two_integer_max_case_def :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"two_integer_max_case_def a b = (case a > b of True ⇒ a | False ⇒ b)"
```

with output

```
consts
  two_integer_max_case_def :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat
```

And I can get value from this definition:

```
value "two_integer_max_case_def 3 4"
```

with output:

```
"4"
  :: "nat"
```

So, this is recognizable and correct expression/term. But I tried to declare lemma using this definition:

```
lemma spec_1:
  assumes "a: nat" "b: nat" "a > b"
  shows "two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
```

Unfortunately, this lemma is not accepted (no goals/subgoals are generated) and instead the error message is given:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "_ set"

Type error in application: incompatible operand type

Operator:  (∈) a :: ??'a set ⇒ bool
Operand:   nat :: int ⇒ nat
```

What is wrong with my lemma? Am I just using incorrectly equality operation (maybe there are some subtleties - confusion of nat instances with sets of nat) or is it more general problem? Maybe I am not allowed to state theorems/lemmas for (possibly interminating) definitions and I can state lemmas only for functions for which the termination proof has been already done (at the time of statement of function)?

**Is it possible to correct (in case if lemma can be stated for definition) my lemma so it gets accepted and generates goals for proof?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with the lemma you propose, the only issue here is how the types of `a` and `b` are declared.

The expression `a: nat` is interpreted as `a ∈ nat` which produces a type error. The error message you're seeing says that the second argument to the `∈` operator, `nat`, should be of type `'a set` but is `int => nat`.

In order to declare the types of variables in a lemma you can use the `fixes` keyword as below.

```
lemma spec_1:
  fixes a :: nat and b :: nat
  assumes "a > b"
  shows "two_integer_max_case_def a b = a"
```